# Laravel-Excel limit() and cursor() don't work with query()

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, laravel-10

I'm trying to use `limit()` (or `take()`) together with `cursor()` to limit the memory usage.

I followed this guide: https://stefanzweifel.dev/posts/2020/02/29/lazy-collections-in-laravel-excel

But it creates empty `.xlsx` (or `.csv`) file:

```
class MyExport implements FromQuery, WithEvents, WithColumnFormatting
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }


    public function query()
    {
        return Model::query()->whereBetween('id', [1000, 1999])->limit(100)->cursor();
    }
    
}
```

Now if I remove `cursor()`, it works, but I noticed that `limit()` has no effect:

```
return Model::query()->whereBetween('id', [1000, 1999])->limit(100);
```

Even with `limit(100)` (or `take(100)`) it will take all the 1000 records. (In the example it's only 1000 so that it won't timeout).

Why don't either of these work? (`cursor()` and `limit()`)?

Comment: if you are using `FromQuery` you need to pass it a query, `->cursor()` returns a lazy collection not a query. In your guide `FromCollection` was being used, not `FromQuery`